# java.util.InputMismatchException using scanner.nextFloat JAVA

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a while condition, that reads from a text file while the file has next float (scanner.hasNextFloat()) and assigns the floats to an array. however, I am getting a java.util.InputMismatchException error.

This is my code:

```
    int index = 0;
    DistanceEventList.resetCurrent();
    String a = "list";
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        if (scanner.hasNextFloat()){
            DistanceEventList.nextCurrent();

            while (DistanceEventList.endList()){
                Float NextScore = scanner.nextFloat();
                DistanceEventList.getCurrent().distance[index] = NextScore;
                DistanceEventList.nextCurrent();}




            DistanceEventList.resetCurrent();

            index ++;}

        else if (scanner.nextLine().equals("list")){


            continue;
    }}
```

The above raises the error, I modified a few things to check where the error was and run this code:

```
    int index = 0;
    DistanceEventList.resetCurrent();
    String a = "list";
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        if (scanner.hasNextFloat()){
            System.out.println(scanner.nextFloat());}

        else if (scanner.nextLine().equals("list")){


            continue;}
}
```

Is there something i am missing here? i cant work out why one gets an input InputMismatchException on the scanner.nextFloat() while the other doesn't.

exert from  text file:

```
65.88782541429404
53.37054214310881
61.51132170748031
60.83640164272022
67.7342725889695
list
65.82330621202783
53.57119546501669
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the while you meet the "list" row.

```
while (DistanceEventList.endList()){
            Float NextScore = scanner.nextFloat();
            DistanceEventList.getCurrent().distance[index] = NextScore;
            DistanceEventList.nextCurrent();}
```

I would add `while (DistanceEventList.endList() && scanner.hasNextFloat())`